# PHP not putting into head?

Tags: php, html, head

I'm trying to make a simple php script that puts a **list in the header**, here is what I have

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
function menu1($link1, $button1) {
echo "<ul><li><a href = '$link1'>$button1</a></li></ul>";}
menu1('index.php','Home')
?>
</head>
<body>
<p>Home</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Yet for some reason when I run the script it outputs this**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li></ul>
<p>Home</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Is there any way I can get this to post in the head?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you talking about the html head? because that's not were the html should go

Comment: @Marz I think you wanted to use `<header>` tag to place the menu.

Comment: Are you checking the output in "view source" or "inspect element"? The browser tend to fix some invalid HTML for you (which your code produces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<head>` element can only contain certain special elements, such as `<title>`, `<link>`, and `<meta>`, among others. It cannot contain any elements which are rendered on the page.

If you view source, you'll see that the markup is being output the way you requested. However, this markup is invalid, and is being "repaired" by the browser by moving these elements into the `<body>`.